# Swagger codegen server-side workflow

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, jersey-2.0, swagger-codegen

I am trying to incorporate swagger-codegen in my new greenfield project, using Java (jaxrs-jersey2).

There are a lot of resources out there already documenting various parts of the project; however, I still haven't been able to find out any high-level advice on the best workflow to use with these tools.

As I understand it, swagger-codegen will be able to generate client-side code to interact with my API, such that I don't have to write this myself. This will happen by looking at a swagger.yaml (2.0) or openapi.yaml (3.0) file. This part is clear.

However, there seems to be multiple ways of generating this specification file. As I understand it, there are two primary ways:

1. Write a server implementation using a combination of jaxrs and Swagger annotations - have a maven plugin run as part of the compile step, generating a swagger.yaml specification file to be used by the client-generation plugin.
2. Write a swagger.yaml specification first, and generate server-stub code  for Jersey, implementing only business logic, separate from all server boilerplate.

Which of these two ways is the recommended workflow? It sounds like (2) means writing less code and focusing on just application logic, without worrying too much about Jersey-specific glue to make the API work. This also means that the single source of truth for the API becomes a simple yaml file, rather than a bunch of Jersey code.

However, I'm unsure how to properly set this up:

1. Does my build need to have a compilation phase where server stubs are constantly regenerated?
2. Do I simply extend from the generated server stub and never worry about annotating API paths with @Path, @GET, etc?
3. Am I misunderstanding the use-case for server-stub generation? I.e. is the first approach (Jersey code-first) more appropriate?
4. If there is no real difference between the two approaches, when would you pick (1) over (2) and vice-versa?

Many thanks.